# Selecting popup message does not redirect to another page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, popup

I have a page that, upon selecting another link on the application, shows a popup asking if I want to save or not.

By selecting "save record", it is saved and then the application redirects to my next page.

By selecting "No" the application also redirects to the next page.

All of that works manually, but does not work when using Selenium. I tried a simple method of `driver.findElement().click()` to using executor and actions class. By selecting "No" I should be able to get redirected to the next page, but this is not happening.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 90); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(PopUpNo)); driver.findElement(PopUpNo).click()

if (driver.findElement(PopUpNo).isDisplayed()) { WebElement ele= driver.findElement(PopUpNo); ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();",ele);}

new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(PopUpNo)).click().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

The xpath for the button used to work before implementing the Popup "Save No;Yes".
Now it does not, so updating xpath fixed that redirect. 
xpath had span by removing it the driver gets redirected